# react native set function not updating variables

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, hybrid-mobile-app, use-effect

I have the below code

```
    const fetchCurrentUser = async () => {
        let u = await firebase.auth().currentUser;
        setUser(u)
        console.log(user)
        let prof = await firebase.firestore().collection('abc').doc(u.uid).get();
        prof === null ? prof = await firebase.firestore().collection('efg').doc(u.uid).get() : null;
        setUserProfile(prof);
        console.log(u)
        console.log(prof)
        console.log(user)
        console.log(userProfile)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchCurrentUser();
    }, [])
```

and the output of the code is

```
someObject()
someObject()
null
null
```

How can user and profile be null when u and prof are non null and just above I set user = u and profile = prof?

What is happening is first time I am getting non null user and then user becomes null (without any action) Not sure how is that possible. because the user I am fetching is from firebase so it should not change without any action

Comment: did you fix your problem?

Comment: @axtck Yes I fixxed my problem. The issue was somewhere else but related to this only. SO i was doing something like
`//do something; setUser(a); if(user == null) //do something;`
The issue was `if(user==null)` was always true because setUser was async and would not immediately set user.
I introduced a local variable and it got fixed

Answer (score 0):

In React, setting state is asynchronous, so if you log it immediately the next line, you won't be able to see the updated state yet.

What you need to do in cases like these is to use `useEffect` with `user` in the dependency array to take actions when `user` changes.

```
    const fetchCurrentUser = async () => {
        let u = await firebase.auth().currentUser;
        setUser(u)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchCurrentUser();
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
      (async () => {
        if(user) { //to ensure that we only take actions if user is actually set
        console.log(user)
        let prof = await firebase.firestore().collection('abc').doc(u.uid).get();
        prof === null ? prof = await firebase.firestore().collection('efg').doc(u.uid).get() : null;
        setUserProfile(prof);
        console.log(u)
        console.log(prof)
        console.log(user)
        console.log(userProfile)
      })()
    }, [user]) //only trigger function when user state changes (and for first render)
```

Comment: cant use await in a non async function

Comment: ah right, will update my answer appropriately

Comment: Just edited my question as well (Last line)

Answer (score 0):

`setState()` happens asynchronously, meaning that by the time you `console.log()` the variables, the variables are still null. You can wait for the state to update in a `useEffect()`, using `useEffect()` as a callback to `setState()`.